# Can't run my script from command prompt - "too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm writing a script to just quickly organize some data that I get, it all comes out in individual CSVs the script compiles it and gives the time stamp.

When I run it in Spyder it works and makes the file. I tried to turn it into a function so I could just run it from the command line, nothing happens. I can run it as a function in spyder though, but when I run it there I call `featable()`. I tried that in PCP but that didnt work either. What am I doing wrong?

```
#Import modules

import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

print ('Starting')

def featable (workspace, basefile, filename):
    print ('Function starting')

#future arguments

path= workspace
primeraw = basefile
newfilename = filename

#Creating base for new file

prime1=pd.read_csv(primeraw,usecols = [i for i in range(3)])
prime=pd.DataFrame(prime1)
print("Base file started")

#Appending Raw Data to Prime
files = os.listdir(path)

for f in files:
    os.chdir(path)
    #get time stamp
    time=str(f[0:5]).replace("-", ":")
    tempfile= pd.read_csv(f,usecols = [i for i in range(4)])
    #append rew data col to to prime
    df=pd.DataFrame(tempfile[' Raw Data (365-15/450-20)'])
    prime[time]=df
    print("Column added")

#Creating new File
prime.to_csv(r"%s/%s.csv" % (path,newfilename),index = False, header=True)

print("Done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    [workspace, basefile, filename] = sys.argv[1:]
    featable (workspace, basefile, filename)
```

Error message:

```
(arcgispro-py3-clone) E:\UA Data>CTF.py('E:/UA Data/Clario_Assay_Data/FEA_6_16/PLATE20','E:/UA Data/Clario_Assay_Data/FEA_6_16/PLATE20/11-32_127_PLATE ID 20_RUN NUMBER 1.CSV','test')
Starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\UA Data\CTF.py", line 49, in <module>
    [workspace, basefile, filename] = sys.argv[1:]
ValueError: too many values to unpack

(arcgispro-py3-clone) E:\UA Data>
```

Comment: How do you call your script from the terminal? It should look like this: `python FILENAME.py arg_1 arg_2 arg_3` (without parenthesis)

Comment: I had called with parenthesis, in the error message. I just tried it without, the format you suggest and I still got  the same error                                                                              
`python CTF.py E:\UA Data\Clario_Assay_Data\FEA_6_16\PLATE21 /E:/UA Data/Clario_Assay_Data/FEA_6_16/PLATE21/11-34_128_PLATE ID 21_RUN NUMBER 1.CSV Test
Starting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CTF.py", line 49, in <module>
    [workspace, basefile, filename] = sys.argv[1:]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Comment: When passing paths with spaces, you'll need to add double quotes before and after, e.g., `python CTF.py "E:/UA Data/Clario_Assay_Data/FEA_6_16/PLATE20" "E:/UA Data/Clario_Assay_Data/FEA_6_16/PLATE20/11-32_127_PLATE ID 20_RUN NUMBER 1.CSV" test`.